# Insert current date and time into table with NOW()

Tags: datetime

I am trying to insert the current date and time into a column that has the datetime type.

I am using this query but it keeps inserting 0000-00-00 00:00:00 into the column (the other fields are inserted fine);

```
 "INSERT INTO importstatus (datumtijd, status, tabelnaam, bestandsnaam, ftpmapnaam) VALUES ('NOW()', 'succes', '".$tabelnaam."', '".$bestand."', '".$dir."')";
```

What is wrong with this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're currently using `' '` between Now() so that's why it's not working.

Try it withouth the `' '`

```
 "INSERT INTO importstatus (datumtijd, status, tabelnaam, bestandsnaam, ftpmapnaam) VALUES (NOW(), 'succes', '".$tabelnaam."', '".$bestand."', '".$dir."')";
```